# Parent element is not resizing correctly with child textarea

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have two elements where one of them is floated to left and other is floated to right and its content is textarea element. Their width is set to 30% and 60%. It looks ok, but when I resize textarea, parent element resizes in strange way. Textarea goes beyond parent.

Here's a simple example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <label>Label</label>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>

  <div style="clear: both;">
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  border: 3px double gray;
  display: inline-block;  
  min-width: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 5px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lq3ks4g/21/)

What is the reason of that strange behavior and what can I do to fix it without modifying HTML code?

Comment: I see nothing strange ... you are having an overflow since you defined the width

Answer (score 0):

> Solution: 1

You can set `max-width: 100%` to `textarea` so that it will not go beyond the `div`

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 3px double gray;
  display: inline-block;  
  min-width: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 5px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
}
.right textarea {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <label>Label</label>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  
  <div style="clear: both;">
  </div>
</div>
```

> Solution: 2

You can set `resize: none;` to `teaxtarea` so that it can't be resized. You can add `height` and `width` of the `textarea` as per your requirement

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 3px double gray;
  display: inline-block;  
  min-width: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 5px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
}
.right textarea {
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <label>Label</label>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  
  <div style="clear: both;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please let me know if  you have any confusion? @alcohol is evil

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lq3ks4g/50/

```
.wrapper {
  border: 3px double gray;
  min-width: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 5px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
}
```

Try removing display:inline-block from .wrapper. Then parent will also expand when textarea expands