# How to make container div (of a given height) increase its height when the textarea inside it is resized?

Tags: css, height

This is my code.

```css
div {
  background: orange;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
textarea {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  width: 75%;
  height: 50%;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea>foo</textarea>
</div>
```

When the `textarea` is resized to make its height greater than the height of the `div`, it overflows outside the `div`. Is there a way to make the container `div` automatically expand to enclose the larger `textarea` when the `textarea` is resized to increase its height?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041743/parent-element-is-not-resizing-correctly-with-child-textarea

Answer (score 0):

changed `height` to `min-height`
basically means that if he has a reason to grow - he will grow, but not be less than the value

You can do the same with the width property, or set the resize to vertical

```css
div {
  background: orange;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
textarea {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  width: 75%;
  height: 50%;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea>foo</textarea>
</div>
```